# Farthest observed protoplanetary disk observed at radio frequencies? Catalog

Tags: observational-astronomy, radio-astronomy, planetary-formation

This could be a naive question or maybe too easy to solve (I do not really know!).

**Brief context**: I'm interested in a certain planetary system at $d \sim 300 \, \mathrm{pc}$. It would be really nice to estimate the disk surface mass $\Sigma(r)$ "observationally" from the infrared part of the spectral energy distribution, as Philip J. Armitage points out in "Astrophysics of Planet Formation" - Cambridge University Press (2020):

> In the mm/sub-mm region of the spectrum (i.e. λ ∼ 1 mm) the bulk of the emission comes instead from optically thin regions of the disk. Taking the limit where the entire disk is optically thin at the frequencies of interest

$$F_\nu = \frac{B_\nu (\overline{T}_\mathrm{dust}) \kappa_\nu}{D^2} \int\limits_{r_{in}}^{r_{out}} \, 2\pi r\, \Sigma \, dr$$

> If we know the distance to the source, the opacity, and the disk temperature, a measurement of the flux density at optically thin wavelengths determines the disk mass

I know there are a few systems resolved, e.g., by ALMA (see [DSHARP](https://www.almaobservatory.org/en/press-releases/alma-campaign-provides-unprecedented-views-of-the-birth-of-planets/))

[image: The researchers will use NASA’s James Webb Space Telescope to survey 17 of the 20 nearby protoplanetary disks observed by Chile’s Atacama Large Millimeter/submillimeter Array (ALMA) in 2018 for its Disk Substructures at High Angular Resolution Project (DSHARP)... Credits: ALMA (ESO/NAOJ/NRAO), S. Andrews et al.; N. Lira]

> The researchers will use NASA’s James Webb Space Telescope to survey 17 of the 20 nearby protoplanetary disks observed by Chile’s Atacama Large Millimeter/submillimeter Array (ALMA) in 2018 for its Disk Substructures at High Angular Resolution Project (DSHARP)... Credits: ALMA (ESO/NAOJ/NRAO), S. Andrews et al.; N. Lira [source](https://www.nasa.gov/feature/goddard/2021/nasa-s-webb-to-explore-forming-planetary-systems)

but I have no information about distances of each one of the disks observed. A quick estimation would be considering

$$\delta_{\mathrm{resol}}\sim \frac{D}{d}$$

where $d \sim 300$ pc is the distance and $D \overset{?}{\sim} 100$ au is the system diameter.

```
D = 100 * u.au
d = 300 * u.pc
(D/d).decompose() * u.rad.to("arcsec")
```

returns 0.33333333

then this *might* (or not) be possible.

**Question**: is there any place where I can find observations sorted by distance? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The NASA exoplanet archive would be an obvious place to start (and end) this search... https://exoplanetarchive.ipac.caltech.edu/